# Why should students who won't need university-level math, still study math and not Logic?

Tags: logic

Sources: 1 [by Tim Gowers](https://www.theguardian.com/commentisfree/2016/mar/11/maths-isnt-problem-curriculum-lacking-imagination).
2 by [Marcus du Sautoy](https://www.theguardian.com/commentisfree/2015/apr/29/people-hate-maths-my-plan-make-it-work-for-them). 3 by [Richard Muller](https://www.quora.com/Why-should-high-school-students-learn-geometry-trigonometry-and-advanced-algebra-It-seems-that-these-subjects-dont-have-much-of-a-practical-application-in-day-to-day-life/answer/Richard-Muller-3).

This question involves only those who won't need university-level math, and accepts that pre-calculus, probability & statistics ought still be taught. Can't studying Logic also teach you the non-quantitative benefits cited below (e.g. thinking, pattern searching, problem solving)? If yes, why prioritize Math over Logic?

> $\Large{\color{limegreen}{{[1.]}}}$ Mathematics should be a tool for increasing one’s thinking power but for many children it is just a set of rather pointless rules for manipulating symbols.
>   [...]
>   It is therefore good for the health of a country if its population has high standards of mathematical literacy: without it, people are swayed by incorrect arguments, make bad decisions and are happy to vote for politicians who make bad decisions on their behalf.
>
> $\Large{\color{limegreen}{{[2.]}}}$ But why should maths be privileged above learning a foreign language or history? Does everyone need to know what a [cosine](https://www.mathsisfun.com/algebra/trig-cosine-law.html) is if the UK is to have a brighter future? Does the success of our economy depend on every citizen feeling confident factorising a [quadratic equation](https://www.theguardian.com/science/video/2013/feb/01/solve-linear-quadratic-equations-tutorial-video)? It may come as a surprise to you that I don’t think so, but I’m still a big believer in teaching maths to 18. What will be important is making sure that the maths we expose students to is both relevant to their future and the future of our country.
>
> What many are not aware of is that maths is so much more than the technical cogs that currently form the backbone of the curriculum. It is about pattern searching, extended analytical and logical thinking, problem solving. I am just embarking on making a new programme for the BBC about the beauty of algorithms. Many of the best algorithms contain no numbers or equations at all, but are full of mathematical thinking. And it is those algorithms that are creating efficient approaches to a whole range of business solutions, from the distribution of goods from supermarket warehouses to decisions about flight schedules at Heathrow airport.
>
> [...]
>
> What about those humanities students or creative artists or vocational students who might argue that they will never need more maths? I believe that even these students, if exposed to the right curriculum, will recognise the benefits of more maths. I am doing an event with the Booker-winning novelist Ben Okri at the Hay festival next month about the connections between mathematical proof and literary narrative. As a novelist, Okri is the first to recognise the importance of a logically consistent narrative to the success of a novel – but also the wonderful benefit that a mathematical sensitivity to pattern and structure can give novelists as they create a narrative arch. From musical composition to carpentry, from street art to journalism, a mathematical mindset potentially gives one an edge.
>
> $\Large{\color{limegreen}{{[3.]}}}$ There is actually no reason to study those if you wish to work at manual labor for the rest of your life. You probably don't need them if you are going to be a sales clerk, or a waiter, or a truck driver.  Those are all honorable jobs, so if that is your goal, there is no need.
>
> On the other hand, if you want to be an engineer, a data analyst, a
>   scientist, or an architect,  then those skills will be part of your
>   everyday life.
>
> If you want to go into business or computers, then you need the
>   ability to think analytically, and to become a problem solver.  Very
>   few subjects studied in high school teach those skills; the
>   predominant one is mathematics.  If you find math difficult, it is
>   likely for precisely that reason: it is the only course you are taking
>   in which you are asked to solve problems that are not absolutely
>   identical to problems you have previously seen.  The key to learning
>   math is recognizing that you are learning approaches, not facts, and
>   think of those approaches as tools towards addressing new ideas.
>
> The skill to "problem solve" is one of the most highly valued skills 
>   in all careers.

Comment: But logic *is* a type of math?

Comment: @Dylan Mathematical Logic, yes. But what of Formal and Informal Logics?

Comment: Informal logic seems to me, at least, as something more to do with rhetorics. Sure, it's useful to learn to identify the different fallacies in a politician's speech. But you can do that with basic mathematical training, even if you can't name these fallacies. And frankly, being able to identify the problem is far more important than knowing the name of the problem. (The quote from Zelazny's Lord of Light about fire and "to speak is to name names" comes to mind.)

Comment: I think problem solving is part of just about every high-school course, be it history, geography, science or auto shop.

Comment: @Dan: Many high school courses focus on the single problem "how to get a passing grade in this course". School is not a place to obtain knowledge, it's a place to train your social skills.

Comment: @AsafKaragila If you don't have a fairly detailed knowledge of how a car works, "brainstorming" about why your car won't start would be a pointless exercise. Meaningful exercises in real-world problem solving should be done in the context of a solid knowledge base.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let me first say that I love logic, both formal and informal, and I think it's important to teach reasoning skills alongside mathematics. Of course, *formal* logic could be seen as just another branch of mathematics, but I guess I am really focusing here on informal logic: being able to analyze everyday arguments, uncover hidden assumptions, detect fallacies, poke through the rhetoric, recognize our cognitive and social biases, detect weak spots in causal reasoning, etc. is enormously valuable, and should be a mandatory component of any education (and this kind of critical thinking can clearly be started *way* before college level).

Indeed, I believe these kinds of general critical thinking skills go a good bit beyond math: no matter how much statistics is thrown at us, at the end of the day too many of us still tend to fall for arguments like "Oh, yeah? Well, I had friend who ...", i.e. we tend to generalize from one or two cases of personal experience and anecdotal evidence. So, an understanding or at least awareness of the typical foibles of human thinking is quite useful (Tim Gowers puts the importance of this rather clearly with his last sentence).

But, mathematics education is clearly really important as well, and one could make an argument that its applications are a good bit broader than just logic. Logic, especially formal logic, is good for learning how to be precise, how it is important to spell out your assumptions, and how to organize your thinking, but it does tend to be rather linear.  But math is about patterns and systems thinking of any kind: non-linear dynamical systems, statistics, game theory, basic calculus, fractals, etc.  All these help us gain a better understanding of the world around us.

And, as especially Marcus du Sautoy points out, you do not have to be a professional mathematician to make use of these concepts. Indeed, as Tim Gowers points out, the 'stupid human skill' of symbol manipulation or, even worse, mindless 'plug and chug' (which, it seems, so much of middle and high school 'math' seems to be obsessed with ... even though presumably this will be one of the first things that AI will take over for us) is *not* what we're talking about here - it is, as du Sautoy puts it, developing and nurturing a mathematical *mindset* that we should be after.

Answer (score 1):

I think that question is akin to asking why we study history or art. Most people won't use any of that information again or the skills they learned in those classes, but we teach them anyway. It's not about whether or not you will use it again, it's about being a more well-rounded individual. Maybe one day in your life, your goals will change, and you'll find yourself needing mathematics and those skills. If you're getting a liberal arts degree, then the goal of that degree is to get an "educated" perspective.

I think the real question is why people don't value their mathematics education as much as their education in say, a business class, when a course in statistics could have a great value in their day to day lives.